# Greasemonkey script to turn off annoying things

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Is there a way I can use Greasemonkey to selectively remove scripts on a site?

Disclaimer: I know JS but don't have much (read: none) direct experience with GM.

I just need to stop external scripts from loading (can't use NoScript because I want to load other less annoying scripts).

I tried doing this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           turn_shit_off
// @namespace      http://www.google.com
// @include        http://www.xyz.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function() {
    var d = document;   // shorthand
    var scripts = d.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.count; i++) {
        if(scripts[i].src.indexOf('foobar.js') != -1) {
            scripts[i].src = '';
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `window.onload` isn't the right way to go because by definition it happens *after* everything is loaded. Dig into the greasemonkey API because most likely you'll need to hook into the browser's capabilities rather than relying on regular javascript.

Comment: AdBlock will let you block any resource from being loaded by specifying a URL pattern.

Comment: GM scripts are delayed 'till DOM ready, so it's likely that even without `window.onload` this script will still run *after* the scripts have ran. Also, I'm quite sure NoScript has a blacklist mode. If it doesn't, you can always look at [YesScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4922/)

Comment: Ok, addblock works great for that, thank you. Should probably be moved to SuperUser?

Comment: You can set NoScript to select which script to load for a particular site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/) is the best way to go, if applicable.

The GM code may not fire in time to stop all the damage, but -- for giggles -- a working version of your code would be something like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           turn_shit_off
// @namespace      http://www.google.com
// @include        http://www.xyz.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var J = scripts.length-1;  J >=0;  --J)
{
    if (/foobar\.js/i.test (scripts[J].src) )
    {
        console.log ("Killed", scripts[J].src);
        scripts[J].parentNode.removeChild (scripts[J]);        
    }
}

/*--- Now you have to unload any unwanted event handlers and/or timers 
    that were set before the above code could fire.
    This is highly page-specific and may not be possible if anonymous
    functions were used.
*/
```

You will see that it actually removes the script elements.
But, alas, altering or removing the `script` elements, by itself, will have no effect most of the time.   Except, *maybe*, in delayed-load/run code (things that fire `onload` or that have the `defer` or `async` attributes set).

You won't have any effect until explicitly countering the handlers and timers that the bogus JS sets -- which is highly page-specific and not always possible.

Run this code to see for yourself.

Comment: Removing script tags from the document after it's loaded actually does nothing at all as far as the JavaScript runtime state is concerned.  Any variables defined by removed scripts will still exist, and any actions taken by them will still have happened.

Comment: @cdhowie: I believe I stated as much in my answer, and that is the reason behind the comment at the end of the code.   The hope was that the GM script could remove some JS before it fires (things that fire `onload` or that have the `defer` or `async` attributes set, perhaps).   All in all, the task is highly problematic with greasemonkey, but since this issue comes up a lot, the discussion is worth having, and some sample code might be illustrative.

Comment: Ah, the reasoning for actually removing the elements would have been good to put in your answer.  It was not clear why you were removing elements only to say "hey, this really doesn't do anything" because you did not mention deferred scripts.  That was the reason behind my comment -- it was unclear exactly why you were removing them.

Comment: @cdhowie: I was removing them because that seemed to be the goal that the OP was striving for in his code/post.  I've edited the answer to make it clearer that this approach is not so easy/effective.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an even shorter one from Matt Sargent on Greasemonkey forum:

```
var badWidget = document.getElementById('challengeWinnersWidget');
badWidget.parentNode.removeChild(badWidget);
```

Simple, elegant, effective!

Comment: Neither does this answer the question nor does it work.